# Excel cell values as dynamic query values

Tags: excel, vba, sql-server-2008

In my Excel sheet, I have a button that runs a SQL query and returns results on time clock interactions. I have two cells called `StartDate` and `EndDate` that are formatted as input cells. I want the statement to look at the ActionDate column and on only return results within the range of those cells.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
 Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
 Dim ConnectionString As String
 Dim StrQuery As String
 Dim StartDate As Date  
 Dim EndDate As Date    

 StartDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value  
 EndDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6").Value    
 cnn.Open ConnectionString
 cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

 StrQuery = "SELECT Employees.EmployeeID, Employees.First_Name, 
 Employees.Last_Name, EmployeeTimeCardActions.ActionTime, 
 EmployeeTimeCardActions.ActionDate, EmployeeTimeCardActions.ShiftStart, 
 EmployeeTimeCardActions.ActionType FROM Employees LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 EmployeeTimeCardActions ON 
 Employees.EmployeeID=EmployeeTimeCardActions.EmployeeID WHERE ActionDate 
 >StartDate  AND ActionDate <  EndDate ;"

 rst.Open StrQuery, cnn****

 Sheets(1).Range("D3").CopyFromRecordset rst
 End Sub
```

I have a syntax error on `rst.Open StrQuery, cnn`, I have marked with ****.

Comment: I took out my connection string, other than that all of my code is there. If more info is needed I will supply. Just couldnt think of much else I could give

Comment: you have a string with StartDate and EndDate. It is not reading it as a variable, its reading those as part of the query String

Comment: Please be aware next month in July 2019, [Microsoft will end support](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2008) for SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2.

Comment: Yeah I am aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use parameterization via the [ADO Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/execute-method-ado-command?view=sql-server-2017) object which avoids the need to concatenate or punctuate data. Specifically, place qmarks `?` in a prepared, data-less SQL statement that is then binded with parameters containing your *StartDate* and *EndDate* values. Do note, with this approach the recordset is created from the `Command.Execute` (not `Recordset.Open`) call.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command                       ' NEW VARIABLE
    Dim ConnectionString As String, StrQuery As String
    Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date    

    StartDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value  
    EndDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6").Value    
    cnn.Open ConnectionString
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

    StrQuery = "SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.First_Name, e.Last_Name, " _
               & "     t.ActionTime, t.ActionDate, t.ShiftStart, t.ActionType " _
               & " FROM Employees e " _
               & " LEFT OUTER JOIN EmployeeTimeCardActions t " _
               & "       ON e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID " _
               & " WHERE ActionDate > ?  AND ActionDate < ?;"

    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = cnn
        .CommandText = StrQuery
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("str_param", adDate, adParamInput, , StartDate)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("end_param", adDate, adParamInput, , EndDate)

        Set rst = .Execute                           ' CREATES RECORDSET
    End With

    Sheets(1).Range("D3").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close: cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing: Set cmd = Nothing: Set cnn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Word. This was great. My sheet is working. Fine tweaks here and there I need to get done, like the sheet clearing and rerunning query when I click the button. Shouldn't be too hard to fix that

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Change your query string so that you are actually referencing your variables:

```
StrQuery = "SELECT Employees.EmployeeID, Employees.First_Name, 
 Employees.Last_Name, EmployeeTimeCardActions.ActionTime, 
 EmployeeTimeCardActions.ActionDate, EmployeeTimeCardActions.ShiftStart, 
 EmployeeTimeCardActions.ActionType FROM Employees LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 EmployeeTimeCardActions ON 
 Employees.EmployeeID=EmployeeTimeCardActions.EmployeeID WHERE ActionDate 
 > '" & StartDate & "' AND ActionDate < '" & EndDate & "';"
```

You may also need to wrap your dates in `'` or `#` depending on the database you are querying.

By the way, it is usually best to parameterize your query string to avoid the possibility  of sql injection; especially since your input mechanism is an Excel range. [Example](https://evona.nl/simple-parameterized-queries-using-ado-in-vba/)

Comment: Yeah I was just trying to get it to work once then I can fine tune. I recreated the tables and join in a dummy db. I had the &s thrown in there and that created the syntax error. My fault about the db, I am using MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: Still getting an error on      (rst.Open StrQuery, cnn)        doesn't like the   WHERE ActionDate 
 > " & StartDate & " AND ActionDate < " & EndDate & ";"

Comment: if you're using SQL Server, you'll need to either pass those dates as date-typed parameters (the best way) or make sure you wrap them in single quotes `'` in a raw sql statement. I'll update my answer with the `'` wrapers

Comment: Hmm. Well that is done but still a syntax error in the same place. Not sure whats wrong there